# OData - $top in $expand doesn't insert "TOP" inside generated EF Query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, odata, automapper

I'm making a web service with OData + Entity Framework for my application. 
After projecting members from Database Entities to Application Model (using AutoMapper ProjectTo), Entity Framework print thousands of rows instead of limiting the rows with $top attribute in OData URL.

```
[HttpGet]
  [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 7, EnsureStableOrdering = false)]
  public virtual SingleResult<TModel> Get([FromODataUri] TKeyType key, ODataQueryOptions<TModel> opts)
  {
     IQueryable<TEntity> data = _db.Set<TEntity>()
        .Where(_db.BuildKeyPredicate<TEntity>(key));

     return SingleResult.Create(GetProjected(opts, data));
  }

private IQueryable<TModel> GetProjected(ODataQueryOptions<TModel> opts, IQueryable data)
  {
     string[] expandedProperties = Helpers.Expand.GetMembersToExpandNames(opts);
     IQueryable<TModel> projected;

     if (expandedProperties.Count() > 0)
     {
        projected = data.ProjectTo<TModel>(null, expandedProperties);
// expandedProperties is an array of string with the names of properties to expand specified in $expand
     }
     else
     {
        projected = data.ProjectTo<TModel>();
     }

     return projected;
  }
```

example URL: http://WEBSERVER/odata/Entity(416)?$expand=Child($top=100)

in the debugger, Child lenght is more than 100... in my case 57k. This is why I use $top :)
I was thinking that Entity Framework automatically translates $top parameter in OData with TOP keyword in query, but this is not happening.

If you want more code/ more documentation please tell me!

Comment: Some times ago I had a similar problem and adding $skip and $count=true to the query solved it.

Comment: This is not related to my question.

Comment: Have you solved this problem ?!

Comment: No. To avoid this problem I separeted the two entities... not elegant, but functional.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this instead of using $expand you can use a **Related Entity Route** like this:

```
http://WEBSERVER/odata/Entity(416)/Child?$top=100
```

In order to make route works you need to implement inside the `EntityController` a `GetChild` action like this:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("({key})/Child")]
public IQueryable<Child> GetChild([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return db.Childs.Where(m => m.EntityId == key);
}
```

For more information about OData v4 Related Entities visit this [Entity Relations in OData v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4)